# Корень ТВОР- с чередованием или омонимичный с проверяемой гласной?

Tags: чередования

**Корень ТВОР- с чередованием гласной или омонимичный корень ТВОР- с проверяемой гласной?**

Задание 9 (сборник п/р Сениной Н.А., 2020):

***ЗАТВОРИТЬ, вскочивший, отраслевой***

В ответах: все эти слова содержат **чередующуюся** гласную в корне.

Я склоняюсь к тому, что корень ТВОР-  в слове ЗАТВОРИТЬ - это корень с проверяемой гласной.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Задание 9 (сборник п/р Сениной Н.А., 2020):
>
> ЗАТВОРИТЬ, вскочивший, отраслевой
>
> В ответах: все эти слова содержат чередующуюся гласную в корне.

**Сенина не права.** В слове ***затвори́ть*** — проверяемая гласная:***затво́р.***

Из справочника «ОРФОГРАФИЧЕСКОЕ КОММЕНТИРОВАНИЕ РУССКОГО СЛОВАРЯ»
http://oross.ruslang.ru/:

> ***затвори́ть*** проверка: ***затво́р***

И далее:

> Корень ***твор-*** (*затворить, затворничество, створка, растворить*)
> **не путать** с корнем ***твар/твор.***

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста, а это только Сенина так некорректно поступает? До нее никто и никогда (я имею в виду, в орфографических справочниках) не путал эти корни, причем все давали дополнительное пояснение по теме?

Answer (score 3):

Каким считать корень ТВОР?

Он действительно **омонимичный**, к чередующемуся корню ТВАР/ТВОР смыслового отношения не имеет, поэтому следовало бы его считать **проверяемым**: ***затворить – затвор.*** Но я полагаю, что в школьной программе возможно упрощение темы, и поэтому его тоже условно относят с чередующимся корням.

Пояснение

1. Разбор слова по составу в современном языке выглядит так: ***за/твор/и/ть.***
2. Но с точки зрения **этимологии** буква Т в этом слове должна объясняться.

Этимология (из словаря Фасмера): Происходит от формы с обобщением т из **отвори́ть**, ср. лит. veriù, vérti «открываю, закрываю», àtveriu «отворяю (дверь)», ùžveriu «затворяю (дверь)», лат. ареriō «открываю», ореriō «закрываю», а также вереть, верея́, вор.

3. Соответственно, Т фактически присоединена к корню, пара глаголов выглядит так: ***отворить – затворить.***  Поэтому смысловой  этимологический корень здесь ВОР (от вертеть), но  при  морфемном разборе это не учитывается.
4. Таким образом, корень ТВОР  является **омонимичным корнем**, но в школьной программе подробно эта тема не рассматривается.

Поэтому **классификация** корней упрощается, корень ТВОР в слове *затворить* относят к общей группе чередующихся корней ТВАР/ТВОР, а более точное понимание считается факультативным. Возможно, две точки зрения по этому вопросу так можно объяснить.

Comment: Посмотрите, пожалуйста, вопрос внимательнее. Там спрашивают про гласную — чередуется она или проверяется.

Comment: Спасибо за замечание, я отвечаю именно на этот вопрос, но, вероятно, не очень ясно, в расчете на понимание автора (а это не совсем корректно). Поэтому я дополню текст, чтобы было понятно всем.

Comment: Спасибо! По поводу самого ответа: мне кажется, что версия банальной ошибки в каком-то сборнике более вероятна, чем предположение о школьной программе. Но это мнение чисто интуитивное, поскольку с тонкостями школьной программы я не знаком до такой степени.

Comment: Здесь еще интересный вопрос о разборе слова "отворить".  Обычно указывается такой разбор: о/твор/и/ть. Здесь приставка О, а как объяснить ее значение? Усечение ОТ?  И тогда для понимания снова нужна этимология.